# Custom CheckBoxView for UITableView Duplicating the Check Marks

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have created a CheckBoxView control for my UITableViewCell. The problem I am facing is that once I checkmark one of the top rows and scrolls the same check mark is visible on the bottom rows. This is because of dequeueresuable rows feature and I want to know how can I fix it. Here is the implementation.

**CheckBoxView.m:**

```
-(instancetype) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {

    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    [self setup];
    [self registerGesturesRecognizers];
    return self;
}

-(void) registerGesturesRecognizers {

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(checkBoxTapped:)];

    [self addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];
}

-(void) checkBoxTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *) recognizer {

    if(self.checkBoxViewSelectionChanged) {
        if(!self.isChecked) {
            self.checkBoxViewSelectionChanged(self,self.isChecked);
            self.isChecked = YES;
        }
        else {
            self.checkBoxViewSelectionChanged(self,self.isChecked);

        }
    }
}

-(void) check {

    [_checkBoxImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"small-check"]];

}

-(void) uncheck {

    _checkBoxImageView.image = nil;
}

-(void) setup {

    self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    self.layer.borderWidth = 0.5f;
    self.layer.borderColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;

    _checkBoxImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(1, 0, 23, 23)];
    [self addSubview:_checkBoxImageView];
}
```

And here is the **cellForRowAtIndexPath** method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    SamplesTableViewCell *cell = (SamplesTableViewCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"SamplesTableViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    Item *sample = [_samples objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    cell.productNameLabel.text = sample.product.name;
    cell.productColorLabel.text = sample.productColor.name;
    [cell.productImageView setImage:sample.productColor.image];

    cell.checkboxView.checkBoxViewSelectionChanged = ^(CheckBoxView *checkBoxView, BOOL isChecked) {

        if(!isChecked) {
            [checkBoxView check];
            checkBoxView.isChecked = YES;
        }
        else {
            [checkBoxView uncheck];
            checkBoxView.isChecked = NO;
        }

    };

    return cell;
}
```

The CheckBoxView is actually a UIView on the Storyboard prototype cell whose class is set to CheckBoxView so it is not created dynamically in the cellForRowAtIndexPath event. When I run the above code and checkmark the top rows and scroll then the same checkmark appears on the lower rows.

**UPDATE:**

Here is my updated code but it still checks and unchecks the rows at the bottom.

```
  cell.checkboxView.checkBoxViewSelectionChanged = ^{

        if(!sample.isSelected) {

            [sample setSelected:YES];
            [cell.checkboxView check];
        }
        else
        {
            [sample setSelected:NO];
            [cell.checkboxView uncheck];
        }


    };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `UIView` should **not** be maintaining the `isChecked` state for your checkbox. As you pointed out, due to cell reuse all the others will then be checked because the same `UIView` is being used.

Your model objects powering your data need to maintain the state, or your controller.

For example:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

   SamplesTableViewCell *cell = (SamplesTableViewCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"SamplesTableViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

   // Some code...

   if ([self.myDatasource[indexPath.row] isChecked]) {
       cell.checkBoxView.isChecked = YES;
   }

   return cell;
}
```

Just some rough pseudocode, but hopefully you get the idea. Potential ways to implement this state maintained is either in the form of model objects, or in your `UIViewController` have an `NSArray` containing an `NSDictionary` representing each row in your `UITableView`, where each key-value pair maintains a particular state for your `UITableViewCell`.